# Code-golf - a descrição é o programa

Tags: independente-de-linguagem

Será aceito no máximo um include (ou arquivo de resources etc) que seja nativo da linguagem (que provavelmente será o que fará toda a parte interessante) e a *descrição do problema* deverá ser o código do mesmo.

**Um exemplo em C:**

```
#include "magica.h"
inicia o programa
dado i igual 5
leia x
se x menor que i
imprime verdadeiro
senao
imprime falso
encerra
```

**magica.h**

```
#define inicia int
#define o
#define programa main(){
#define dado int
#define igual =
#define x
#define leia ,d=0;scanf("%d",&d);
#define se if(
#define menor d<
#define que
#define imprime
#define verdadeiro )printf("verdadeiro");
#define senao else
#define falso printf("falso");
#define encerra return 0;}
#include<stdio.h>
```

## O desafio:

```
Dado um vetor com 20 elementos
no qual o primeiro eh 1 e o ultimo 20 e os 
elementos intermediarios sao incrementos do mesmo
Seja i um inteiro,
para i de 3 a 15 faca
se o elemento i do vetor eh um numero primo 
imprima i
fim do programa
```

## Nota:

Serão aceitas **pequenas** alterações no texto desde que não modifiquem o sentido do mesmo.
Será escolhida a resposta mais votada pela comunidade antes de 7 de julho (uma semana).

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre Code Golf, definido no Stack Overflow Meta como fora de escopo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, mas parece que a maioria do meta [concorda](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf) em ter code golf.

Comment: É, a comunidade está bem dividida nesse aspecto... Vou morder a isca: se a pergunta não for fechada até eu ter uma resposta, vou postar. :P

Comment: É uma questão ainda muito dividida @DeMarco como podes ver [nesta resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1027/7210)

Comment: Essa pergunta realmente mostra o quanto a comunidade está dividida: A pergunta tem 2 votos a favor (nenhum contra) e 4 votos para fechar.

Comment: Para quem não tem reputação suficiente para ver as contagens positivas e negativas dos votos, o que o @JorgeB. se refere é que o item sobre Code Golf na pesquisa de opinião está com +19/-11, mostrando que tanto muita gente quer quanto muita gente não quer. Da mesma forma, nessa pergunta em particular 4 votaram pra fechar e 3 votaram pra deixar aberta (até agora).

Comment: Acho que é interessante tem Code Golf aki, já que a comunidade existente é em inglês e não queremos criar uma inteiramente nova só para usar outra lingua, vou ver no que isso vai dar :)

Comment: Já disse várias vezes que não gosto desse tipo de pergunta, mas por coerência com a votação atual no meta, ela deve ficar aberta.

Comment: Li tudo que escreveram, mas até agora a minha pergunta continua a mesma... Qual é a pergunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Prolog (38 linhas)

magica.pro

```
/* Defino minha mini-linguagem */

:-op(10, fy, [dado, um, vetor, com, no, qual, o, primeiro, eh, ultimo, intermediarios, 
              sao, incrementos, do, seja, para, se, elemento, imprima, fim]).
:-op(20, xfy, [elementos, e, um, de, a, do, primo]).
:-op(30, xfy, [faca]).

/* Defino os comandos da minha mini-linguagem */

term_expansion((dado um vetor com _ elementos no qual o primeiro eh A e o ultimo B e
os elementos intermediarios sao incrementos do mesmo), vetor(V)) :-
    criar_vetor(A,B,V).

term_expansion((seja i um inteiro), inteiro(i)). % Não interessa...

term_expansion((para I de A a B faca C), _) :-
    criar_vetor(A,B,V), % Seja um vetor de A a B
    member(X,V),        % e X um membro desse vetor
    chame(C,I,X),       % Faça o que foi pedido, usando I como alias pra X
    fail.               % Faça de conta que falhou. Tente de novo, com um novo membro
term_expansion((para _ de _ a _ faca _), feito). % Todos os números de A a B foram visitados

chame((se o elemento I do vetor eh um numero primo ProximaInstrucao), I, X) :-
  vetor(V),
  elemento(X,V,E),
  (primo(E) -> chame(ProximaInstrucao, I, E)).

chame((imprima I), I, X) :-
    writeln(X).

term_expansion(fim do programa, fim_do_programa). % Não interessa...

/* Implemento os comandos */

criar_vetor(A,A,[A]).
criar_vetor(A,B,[A|R]) :-
  A < B,
  A1 is A + 1,
  criar_vetor(A1,B,R).

elemento(_,[],_) :- fail.
elemento(1,[E|_],E) :- !.
elemento(X,[_|R],E) :-
    X1 is X - 1,
    elemento(X1,R,E).

primo(X) :-              % X não é primo se
    X1 is X - 1,
    criar_vetor(2,X1,V), % dado um vetor de 2 a X-1
    member(Y,V),         % existe um Y membro desse vetor
    0 =:= X mod Y,       % tal que X é multiplo de Y
    !, fail.
primo(_).                % Caso contrário ele é primo
```

codegolf.pro

```
:-include(magica).

dado um vetor com 20 elementos
no qual o primeiro eh 1 e o ultimo 20 e os 
elementos intermediarios sao incrementos do mesmo.
seja i um inteiro.
para i de 3 a 15 faca
se o elemento i do vetor eh um numero primo 
imprima i.
fim do programa.
```

Testado no Swi-Prolog 6.6.5. [Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/kfbKZ5).

Comment: não foi difícil escolher a resposta, afinal foi a única. Uma pena que a questão foi fechada.